# How to pass Object data from fragment to fragment in Serializable?

Tags: android

My issue is `Bundle bundle=getArgument();` is null.

I try `ActivitySerializable activitySerializableTest=(ActivitySerializable)bundle.getSerializable("activitySerializable");` is null too.

How can i get the value from Object when my layout is fragment ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Serializable calss like this:

```
    public class ActivitySerializable implements Serializable {
      private String EDUTITLE;

      public String getEDUTITLE() {
            return EDUTITLE;
        }

      public void setEDUTITLE(String EDUTITLE) {
            this.EDUTITLE = EDUTITLE;
        }
}
```

My A fragment try to set the value like this:

```
    public class ActivityListDomesticFragment extends Fragment{

    .......

    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            ActivitySerializable activitySerializable=new ActivitySerializable();

            activitySerializable.setEDUTITLE("Value");

            //set the Bundle

            ActivityContents activityContentsFragment=new ActivityContents();//i want to get value from this fragment

            Bundle serializableBundle=new Bundle();


            serializableBundle.putSerializable("activitySerializable",activitySerializable);


            activityContentsFragment.setArguments(serializableBundle);//send bundle

            switchFragment(activityHomePage);//switch to next Fragment
    }
//change fragment function
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment, null);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

my B fragment get value like this:

```
public class ActivityContents extends Fragment{
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contents_fragment, container, false);


            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            // it shows my activitySerializableTest is on a null object reference
            ActivitySerializable activitySerializableTest=(ActivitySerializable)bundle.getSerializable("activitySerializable");

                    String test=activitySerializableTest.getEDUIN();
                    activityCtEduin.setText(test);
                    if (bundle != null) {
                    String EDUTITLE=activitySerializable.getEDUTITLE();
                        activityCtTitle.setText(EDUTITLE);
            else{
               //bundle is null
            }
            return view;
        }
}
```

I change to ActivityContents by click MainActivity drawer item.
Here is its layout:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.user.taiwandigestionsociety_v11.MainActivity">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

//fragment change over here-------------------------------------
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My MainActivity about change the fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
.......

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
if (id == R.id.activitiesContents) {
            //here is change to ActivityContents fragment
            switchFragment(ActivityContents.newInstance());
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the class name of your B fragment?

Comment: i updated it , it is public class ActivityContents extends Fragment  (B fragment)

Comment: Please show us how you display ur fragment after setting it's arguments

Comment: How i display the fragment ? do you mean my layout or what ?

Comment: I change to ActivityContents  Fragment is from my navigationDrawer menu.

Comment: Please add code, you are setting arguments on the `activitySerializableTest` , how do u use this variable ??

Comment: It's a getter and setter , i had post it on `public class ActivitySerializable implements Serializable` . Dose not mean this ?

Comment: `switchFragment(activityHomePage);` is in my A fragment when i finish the setting of bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The `Fragment` should not call `getArguments` as an initializer for a field. Call it from a lifecycle callback, such as `onCreateView`. When the object is being created, the arguments haven't been set yet, so the current code will always get back a `null`.

You should also look into using `Parcelable` instead of `Serializable` as it is more efficient. Also, if your arguments are primitives or strings, there is no need to use a `Serializable` or `Parcelable`, the `Bundle` will handle primitive types and strings directly.

Comment: thanks for your responding , my `Bundle bundle=getArguments();` is under onCreatView where i just ignore it .

I had try it by only pass by Bundle , it succeed.  I use Serializable not Bundle because my project have to complete by saving value in Object.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow what you are saying.  I'd suggest updating and cleaning up the code to reflect what you mean and to clearly show what is happening.

Comment: It's ok , i updated again.  The issue is when i compile `ActivitySerializable activitySerializableTest=(ActivitySerializable)bundle.getSerializable("activitySerializable");` , it shows on a null object reference

Comment: it told me Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Check to be sure that the `Bundle` is actually being returned.  I'd also suggest using a `static final String` (i.e. constant) for the key used to set/get the object from the `Bundle`.  Eliminate the possibility of a spelling mistake when both the `Activity` and the `Fragment` use a quoted string directly.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion . I know the point which is static final String , i use ctrl+c and ctrl+v , so i'm sure it is correct unless when i test it.

Comment: From the updated code, where is `activityContents` actually added to a `FragmentTransaction`?  The only thing shown here is a call to `switchFragment` which is passed some other `Fragment`, `activityHomePage`.

Comment: Ok i updated code that is include layout and how to switchFragment to ActivityContents . I though that  is not the reason for my bundle is null. 
Please take a look , thanks. thanks for your attention aganin :)

Comment: The problem is that `ActivityListDomesticFragment` is creating a new `ActivityContents` and setting the arguments on it, then doing nothing with it.  The `ActivityContents` is created in your `onClick`, so your arguments need to be set there.

Comment: If i have to set arguments on specified that i don't need to use Serializable. 
My condition is that i have a lots fragments . No matter how fragment is where i can get the value on ActivityContents when i start ActivityListDomesticFragment  .

Comment: I reference your sugestion , i change `switchFragment(activityHomePage);` into  `switchFragment(activityContentsFragment);`  . The bundle is no more null , but i don't want to change by this in my condition.

Comment: Can't i setArguments(Bfragment), when i change to any fragment ?

Comment: Hey @Larry Schiefer , i update my question again on another page , may be it will more clear for what is my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240479/how-to-send-object-value-from-fragment-to-fragment-in-serializable

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to save my issue , it is about singleton:

I use it for my Book class like this:

```
public static Book book=null;

    public static Book getBook(){
        if (book==null){
            book=new Book();
            return book;
        }else {
            return book;
        }
    }
```

in A:

```
Book book=Book.getBook();
book.setName("Jerry");
```

in C:

```
Book book=Book.getBook();
textView.setText(book.getName());
```

then my issue is over , i have to give up Serializable on my condition.