# How to send Object value from fragment to fragment in Serializable?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, serializable

My condition is that i have three fragments A、B、C , i set the value in Afragment and get the value in Cfragment.

I want change layout into Bfragment when in Afragment.

Compile the project shows `Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`  that i change layout into Cfragment when in Bfragment.

I want to use Serializable that can let me get the value in Cfragment.

How do i finish it ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Serializable bean:

```
public class Book implements Serializable {
    String name;

    public Book(){

    }

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        A a=new A();
        switchFragment(a);
    }

    public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, fragment, null);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Afragment:

```
public class A extends Fragment {

    B b=new B();

    public A() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        Book book=new Book();
        book.setName("Jerry");
        //try to send the value to Cfragment
        C c=new C();
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("name",book);
        c.setArguments(bundle);


        //change layout into Bfragment
        Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switchFragment(b);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, fragment, null);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Bfragment:

```
public class B extends Fragment {

    C c=new C();

    public B() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        //change layout into Cfragment
        Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switchFragment(c);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, fragment, null);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Cfragment:

```
public class C extends Fragment {

    Book book;

    public C() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);

        TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textC);
        //try to get the setting value from Aframent 
        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        book=(Book) bundle.getSerializable("name");
        textView.setText(book.getName());

        return view;
    }

}
```

According to CoDFather respond that i change like this :

```
public static C newInstance(String param1) {
        C fragment = new C();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Book book=new Book();
        book.setName(param1);
        args.putSerializable("name", book);  // in your case it is serializable
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

in A:

```
C.newInstance("Jerry");
```

in C onCreate:

```
Book book=(Book) getArguments().getSerializable("name");
        textView.setText(book.getName());
```

When B to C :
it shows `Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference` in return fragment

Comment: Consider using parcelable instead of serializable.

Comment: The code is correct its seems but your sending argument from A to B not from B to C, so at C its null, you have to send it from B to C.

Code excuation is wrong.

Comment: The same Question you asked before and I again asking you how you use the object of `C` fragment that you has setting arguments to it, please see the answer for more details

Comment: Please use recommended way of fragment communication 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
This way you will save creating unnecessary object creations and  a more clear and robust communication between fragments

Comment: @Utsav Shrestha , i know it . I just get a test.

Comment: @Atef Hares , how i use is Bfragment to Cfragment , i think the question is more clearer to understand my issue.

Comment: @徐博俊  Check the answer again, I updated it

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment `A` you are doing that

```
C c=new C();
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("name",book);
c.setArguments(bundle);
```

But you did not used this `c` object from your `C` fragment.

Instead in your Fragment `B`
you defined `C c=new C();` which is a completely new object of your `C` fragment then you switched to this new `c` without setting arguments.

**Simply, You are setting arguments on an object and then you use another one!
That is why `getArguments()` returen null**

If you want to pass the arugments from `A` to `C` you need to get it from `A` into `B` first the pass it again to `C`

in `B` in `onCreateView`

```
c.setArguments(getArguments());
```

Then you can switch to this `c`

Comment: thanks ,you let me know the object problem, but A>B>C is not what i want , if i have D、E、F...etc  , D or E or F change to Cfragment , it is not a effective solution i though.

Comment: do u mean you want to pass the object of `Book` from any other fragment  (`D` or `E` or `F` or what ever) to `C` ?

Comment: yes,  but i want to change layout not pass object . I can get the value in Cfragment from Book.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment A do this

```
    B b=new B();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("name",book);
    b.setArguments(bundle);
```

in fragment B

```
    C c=new C();
    c.setArguments(getArguments());
```

and use `switchFragment(c);`

> The reason why `getArguments()` return null is, you are setting arguments
>   to one and using the other.

But it is not recommended way to do it. use `newInstance` instead.

```
public static C newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        C fragment = new C();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);  // in your case it is serializable
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

and in on create

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
```

and use `C.newInstance(params1,params)` . In your case replace it with bundle.

Comment: thanks, but A>B>C is not what i want , i change to use newInstance , it's not working the same just like i update in my question.

Comment: thanks @CoDFather , but what is mParam1 and where is my Book object ?

Comment: @徐博俊 you can use as your own way

Comment: @徐博俊 change parms with your books class objects

Comment: hey @CoDFather , i reference your suggest and change my code , it show error again , i update in my question.

Comment: @徐博俊 dude then you should try with database for this purpose

Comment: oh no~ is it really can only do so ?

Comment: hey i found a solution , it can save my condition like this.

Comment: Sure , i post it before a few minutes , it had been deleted by system :(

I post it again.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to save my issue , it is about singleton:

I use it for my Book class like this:

```
public static Book book=null;

    public static Book getBook(){
        if (book==null){
            book=new Book();
            return book;
        }else {
            return book;
        }
    }
```

in A:

```
Book book=Book.getBook();
book.setName("Jerry");
```

in C:

```
Book book=Book.getBook();
textView.setText(book.getName());
```

then my issue is over , i have to give up Serializable on my condition.